# How to implement and use the `buildIf` function in the @functionBuilder structure correctly?

Tags: view, swiftui, dsl

i what to know more about SwiftUI, so i decided to make my own functionBuilder.

I made something like this:

```swift
public static func buildBlock<Content>(_ contents: Content...) -> Content {
        return CombinedContent(with: contents)
    }
```

And it works as expected

But i can't understand what should i do with `buidIf` function.
Does it should takes optional content and if it's nil return empty View or something?

I would also like to know how does it works under all this abstractions.
Thanks

Comment: Like you, I'm learning. :-) The documentation suggests (to me) two things - `buildIf` is a method *within* `ViewBuilder`, and it's signature takes `content:Content?` as input and `Content?` as output. So when building your view, pass in whatever content you have - if any - and if `buildIf` is false it will return what was passed. If true? *that's* where you add to the content. Do you have more specific code where we can reproduce what you are asking?